# Rename Object not supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I tried to run the following commands in SQL DW:

```
RENAME OBJECT dbo.test TO test2
RENAME OBJECT test TO test2
```

Both failed with the following error:

> No item by the name of '[DemoDB].[dbo].[test]' could be found in the current database 'DemoDB', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

Is this a defect or is there a workaround that I can use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RENAME` is now supported. In order to use `RENAME OBJECT` you must prefix the table you want to change with the schema name like this:

```
RENAME OBJECT x.T_New TO T;
```

Notice that there is no schema qualification on the target. This is because the renamed object must continue to reside inside the same schema. To transfer a table from one schema to another you need to use the following command:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER OBJECT::x.T_NEW;
```

Comment: Quick Update - the fix for this is coming within the next 2 weeks!

Comment: Quick FYI - this fix only supports renaming a table within the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking at the time. It posible now in Azure Synapse Analytics, formely Azure SQL Datawarehouse; you can go with:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
MODIFY NAME = Northwind;
```